# Security update should take 5GB. I have 36GB available but somehow it's not enough

Tags: high-sierra, software-update

I've tried to install security update 2019-002 on my HighSierra in 3 different ways. Through the App Store, the terminal (softwareupdate) and the file I've downloaded from Apple's site. The result is always the same. I restart, it starts installing and then I get the message "macOS could not be installed on your computer. The target disk is too small for this operation- Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again."

The thing is, I have plenty of space available. The update requires 5.31GB of space and my disk has 36.68GB available:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to temporarly free up additional space?  Maybe copying Xcode to the icloud?  if you have Xcode.  I suggest Xcode because its so large.

Comment: I tried that. No luck. It doesn't matter how much space I free up, It always shows the same warning.